# Setup Project with JSF2.0 & Prime Faces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am try to setup JSF project with prime faces library 
  When I run this setup it shows be following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: null source
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:54
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:417)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

I did not able to find out reason behind it .
 following is by setup

Folloing are the library I included into web-inf/lib 
  1. jsf-api-2.0.3.jar 
  2. jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar 
  3. jstl-1.0.2.jar 
  4. primefaces-3.4.jar

Following are the entrires into web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.skin</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list> 
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.nsf.ecap.web.base.ECapStartUpServlet
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

login.xhtml

```
<h:body>   

 <CENTER>  

     <h:panel header="Login Form">    
     <h:Form>  
         <h:PanelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">  
         <h:outputLabel value="UserName" for="#{loginBBean.userInfo.username}"> </h:outputLabel>
         <h:inputText value="#{loginBBean.userInfo.username}" label="UserName">   </h:inputText>  
         <h:outputLabel value="Password" for="#{loginBBean.userInfo.password}"></h:outputLabel>  
         <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBBean.userInfo.password}"></h:inputSecret>  
         <h:commandButton value="Login" type="submit" action="#{loginBBean.doLogin}"></h:commandButton>   

        </h:PanelGrid>  

    <h:messages>
    </h:messages>



    </h:Form>
    </h:panel>
</CENTER>  
</h:body>  
</html>
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="<%=basePath%>">

    <title>My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page</title>    
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">      
    <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="keyword1,keyword2,keyword3">
    <meta http-equiv="description" content="This is my page">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    -->
  </head>

  <body>        
    <jsp:forward page="jsp/login/login.jsf"/>      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you browse directly to `jsp/login/login.jsf` ? also dont use jsp in JSF 2 , use facelets only... try to remove the `com.nsf.ecap.web.base.ECapStartUpServlet` listener to see if it works without it

Comment: the reason behind the exception could be anything. first you do not use primefaces tags. primefaces tags start with <p: tag. second do you add page directives to your jsf page? third, your url pattern entry in web.xml is .jsf meaning that jsf works with only pages whose extension is .jsf. change it \*/faces/\* and add /faces/ to your url after site name or local host. try again and post the exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

"My JSP 'index.jsp' starting page"? Please block/ignore/throwaway that tutorial you're reading now. [It's only completely confusing you and teaching you bad practices](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/06/what-is-it-with-roseindia.html).

---

As to your list of libraries:

> Folloing are the library I included into web-inf/lib
>
> 1. jsf-api-2.0.3.jar
> 2. jsf-impl-2.0.3.jar
> 3. jstl-1.0.2.jar
> 4. primefaces-3.4.jar

First of all, the JSTL version is wrong. It should be at least JSTL 1.1 or preferably 1.2. The EL (expression language, those `${}`/`#{}`) things would otherwise fail to work. Remove jstl-1.0.2.jar and put [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in place.

Further it looks okay. It only surprises me that you've more than 2 years old JSF API/impl versions while you've a fairly recent (less than 2 weeks) PrimeFaces version. I'd align those JSF API/impl versions as well to be the [latest available](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/). It's currently already at [2.1.13](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.13/javax.faces-2.1.13.jar) (note: it's now composed of only one JAR file javax.faces.jar instead of two JAR files).

---

As to your `web.xml`:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

This is declared conform Servlet 2.5 spec which is over 6 years old already. Are you sure that you're running such an outdated container? Given the presence of the JSF and JSTL libraries, I assume that you're using Tomcat. The current Tomcat version, 7.x, exist more than 2 years already and is Servlet 3.0 compatible. You should declare your `web.xml` to match the highest supported version of the target container.

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

Further, those `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` and `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` entries represent the **default** values already. Just get rid of them to minimize noise.

---

As to your `login.xhtml`:

```
<h:Form>  
     <h:PanelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="2">
```

Tag names are case sensitive. The `<h:Form>` and `<h:PanelGrid>` doesn't exist at all. It are `<h:form>` and `<h:panelGrid>`.

```
<CENTER>
```

While not immediately a problem, but this HTML element is **deprecated** since 1998 in favor of CSS. Also, seeing it in uppercased flavor instead of `<center>`, which is very typical for pre-90's HTML style, doesn't give me the impression that you're reading the most recent and right books/tutorials to learn web development. You should assure that your learning resources are up to date.

---

As to your `index.jsp`: this is completely useless. Remove it altogether. Just change your `web.xml` from

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list> 
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

and this way `login.xhtml` will show up as "home page" when you access `/` in your webbrowser. Note that you shouldn't and don't need `*.jsf` URL pattern anymore.

---

#### See also:

- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - at the bottom you can find decent JSF 2.0 resources

Comment: Oh my god... that Roseindia article I laughed so hard when I saw the Swing JOptionPane being displayed from a JSF event!  I didn't even think that was possible until I realized that his server running localhost is launching the window.