# How can I redirect to a plain HTML page in JSF action method?

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have a plain HTML page `error.html`. When I use

```
return "error.html?faces-redirect=true";
```

it will actually redirect to `error.xhtml`, not `error.html`.

How can I redirect to a non-JSF page in a JSF action method?

Comment: Make sure you have configured everything as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405317/757071

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3311721/757071

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The navigation case outcome is treated as a JSF view. So it always expects a JSF view. If renaming `error.html` to `error.xhtml` is not possible for some unclear reason (remember, you can safely use plain HTML in a Facelets page), then you'd need to send a redirect to a non-JSF resource *yourself* using [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29).

```
public void someAction() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/error.html");
}
```